# How to use Scattertext with only two targets

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a dataset with these type of label: Words, Zeros and Ones (See image) Numbers are the frequencies for each word. I would like to apply "scattertext".I tries a script, but I wrong, I don't know where. It is possible to apply "scattertext"? How can I do?

[image]

```
# Load the dataset into a pandas dataframe.
import pandas as pd
import scattertext
Myrepo = pd.read_csv("MyResult.csv", delimiter=',', error_bad_lines=False)
Myrepo
# Label each excerpt with the name of business using the metadata parameter
corpus_dataframe = Myrepo
html = scattertext.produce_scattertext_explorer(corpus,
                                                category='Zeros',
                                                category_name='Zeros',
                                                not_category_name='Unos',
                                                width_in_pixels=1000,
                                                metadata=corpus_dataframe['Words'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is covered in the documentation: https://github.com/JasonKessler/scattertext/#visualizing-differences-based-on-only-term-frequencies .